# RequireJS: require a module return a function instead of a object

Tags: module, requirejs

I'm noticing a strange behaviour with RequireJS trying to assign a simple module value directly to a variable, like this:

```
App.tables = require(['appTables']);
```

The result of this call is that App.tables contain this function:

```
localRequire(deps, callback, errback)
```

while my appTables.js looks like this:

```
define({
  users: {
    name: 'tables.users',
    data: {
      name: {
        visible: true,
        hide: false,
        display: 'Name'
      },
      surname: {
        visible: true,
        hide: false,
        display: 'Surname'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Indeed trying to assign it in the classic way works:

```
require(['appTables'], function(appTables) {
    App.tables = appTables;
});
```

So what's wrong with my first approach? Why does it return a function instead of the object? Thanks!

Comment: You should be passing the name of the module to `require`, not an array. So: `App.tables = require('appTables');` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it gives me the following error: "Error: Module name "appTables" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])"

Comment: You need to wrap the `require` inside a `define` block when you use the simplified CommonJS syntax. So: `define(function(require) { App.tables = require('appTables'); ... });` should work. See: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule

Comment: Thanks again, but another error come out: "Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require) {
      App.tables = require('appTables');
    }".
Anyway the whole point was to find a way to semplify the things but I don't think it's possible, I guess I could live using require in the normal way. Thanks anyway for your help! :)

Comment: Where are you calling this from? The simplified commonjs syntax is for defining dependencies inside a module.

Comment: I'm calling that inside my main.js module.

Comment: You can't use the commonjs format in that context. It's meant to be used within a module, as an alternative to the amd format where you assign an array of module dependencies to function arguments.

Comment: Well, thanks for the clarification, so I guess I should stick with the regular requirejs syntax...

Comment: Yes, see also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872152/why-use-alternate-requirejs-define-definefunctionrequire/13872414#13872414

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplified CommonJS format which you're using (`App.tables = require('appTables')`) is meant to be used within a module, as an alternative to the amd format where you assign an array of module dependencies to function arguments. It is not meant to be used in your `main.js` module (just use the standard `require('appTables', function(appTables) { ... });` format for that).

In a module, you would wrap the `require` call in a `define` block, and pass the module name (`'appTables'`):

```
define(function(require) {
  appTables = require('appTables');
  ... do something with appTables ...
});
```

See the documentation on the [Simplified CommonJS Wrapper](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule) for details.

See also: [Why use alternate requirejs define: define(function(require) { ... }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872152/why-use-alternate-requirejs-define-definefunctionrequire/13872414#13872414)

Comment: This gives the error `Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`. It would also presumably import this module (or at least look it up) each time this function is used which is not ideal.